# CMD no reconoce comando tsc -v (TYPESCRIPT)

Tags: angular, typescript, cmd, instalacion

Muy buenas. Estoy intentando instalar Angular CLI. He instalado node y npm, y pensaba que también había instalado typescript, pero cuando compruebo si éste ha sido instalado a través del comando `tsc -v` me salta el siguiente mensaje: `"tsc" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable`. ¿A qué se debe esto? ¿Significa que no ha sido instalado? Gracias y un saludo

Comment: ¿Qué comando usaste para instalar typescript? Puedes ver esto por si te sirve: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para instalar TypeScript y lo reconozca como comando en el CMD or Terminal tienes que instalar el modulo de manera global con el comando:

```
npm install -g typescript
```

Una vez instalado en cualquier ubicación puedes mandar a llamar `tsc nombreDelArchivo.ts`

**NOTA: Recuerda cerrar la ventana de CMD o Terminal para cargar nuevamente los comandos instalados**

RTFM: https://www.typescriptlang.org/#download-links